# Given $a^b \pmod {c}$, $a^b \pmod {d}$, $a^b \pmod {e}$, how can $a^b mod (c*d*e)$ be deduced?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81228/how-do-i-compute-ab-bmod-c-by-hand) covered large exponents on the $b$ side. What about the $m$ side?

Given:

$$a^b \pmod m$$

where $m$ is a large compound number.

For example:

Given

$$5^{2003} \pmod {7} \equiv 3$$
$$5^{2003} \pmod {11} \equiv 4$$
$$5^{2003} \pmod {13} \equiv 8$$

how can one quickly deduce:

$$5^{2003} mod (7*11*13)$$

Comment: [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem)

Comment: as well as chinese remainder theorem you may need:  if $a\equiv b\pmod n$ then $\frac a{\gcd(a,n)}\equiv \frac b{\gcd(a,n)}\pmod {\frac n{\gcd(a,n)}}$ if the moduli are not relatively prime.

Answer (score 1):

Let the number be $x$.

Then we get from the *Chinese Remainder Theorem*:
$$5^{2003}\pmod{7\cdot 11\cdot 13}\equiv x\iff\begin{cases}x\pmod 7\equiv 3\\x\pmod{11}\equiv 4\\ x\pmod{13}\equiv 8\end{cases}$$

The following is one method to apply the *Chinese Remainder Theorem*.

From the 3rd equation:
$$x=13k+8\tag 4$$

Combine with the 1st equation:
$$13k+8\equiv -k+1\equiv 3\pmod 7\implies k=7l-2$$
Substitute in (4):
$$x=13(7l-2)+8=13\cdot7l-18\tag 5$$
Combine with 2nd equation:
$$13\cdot7l-18\equiv 3l+4\equiv 4\pmod{11} \implies l=11m$$
Substitute in (5):
$$x=13\cdot7\cdot 11m -18 \equiv -18\pmod{7\cdot 11\cdot 13}$$

Comment: Where exactly does $5^{2003}$ come in here?

Comment: @JohnZhau, the 3 given equations are derived from it. E.g. $5^{2003}\pmod 7\equiv (5^{333})^6\cdot 5^5\equiv 1\cdot (-2)^5\equiv 3$. Since you already have those equations, we don't see it anymore.

Comment: The chinese remainder theorem says there is only one such value $x$ that is congruent to those values and mods.  So as $5^{2003}$ is congruent to those values, it must be that $5^{2003} \equiv x \pmod {7*11*13}$.  So solve for $x$ and that will solve for $5^{2003}$.

Comment: tl;dr.... Let $x = 5^{2003}$.  Solve for $x$.  $x\equiv -18\pmod{7*11*13}$ therefore..... $5^{2003} \equiv -18\pmod{7*11*13}$